How to send files in aiogram useing telethon?
I try to send files in aiogram using telethon, but if I try to send two or more files (I just send to telegram bot "send_file" command multiple times) at the same time, telethon client sends only first file
heres my code:
main.py
@dp.message(F.text == 'send_file')
async def send_file(message: Message):
    await message.answer('sending file...')

    async with client:
        await client.send_file(message.from_user.id, "vid.mp4")

file_sender.py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events
import asyncio

api_id = 123
api_hash = "1234"

client = TelegramClient('name', api_id, api_hash)

I also tried this:
main.py
@dp.message(F.text == 'send_file')
async def send_file(message: Message):
    await message.answer('sending file...')
    await send_file(message.from_user.id)

file_sender.py
async def send_file(user_id):
    async with client:
        await client.send_file(user_id, "vid.mp4")


Welcome. To get an answer, you should provide more information. Are you getting any errors? What is the code actually doing? Does all code execute? Does it get stuck anywhere? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

bot.send_media_group?  for telethon you can pass in a list of files like client.send_file(user_id, [filename1, filename2, ...])
